# How to UPSERT using where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, insert-update

I surf through the internet to find and answer to this but I couldn't find a answer.

I want to check four columns before update or insert. I cant use INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE because it doesn't allow a where clause. so I tried to use following statement that was created by me.

```
"SELECT COUNT(id) INTO @count FROM room_prices WHERE (hotel_di = $hotel_id AND room_id = $room_id AND period_id = $periodId AND meal_plan_id = $mealPlanId) "
                . "IF @count > 0 THEN "
                . "UPDATE room_prices SET price = $price WHERE (hotel_di = $hotel_id AND room_id = $room_id AND period_id = $periodId AND meal_plan_id = $mealPlanId) "
                . "ELSE "
                . "INSERT INTO room_prices (hotel_id, room_id, period_id, meal_plan_id, price) VALUES ($hotel_id, $room_id, $periodId, $mealPlanId, $price) "
                . "END IF"
```

but this one also not working. it gives this error.

**The query you submitted is not valid.**

is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Start with a unique index on `hotel_id`, `room_id`, `period_id`, `meal_plan_id`:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_room_prices_4 on room_prices(hotel_id, room_id, period_id, meal_plan_id)
```

Then you can use `on duplicate key update`:

```
INSERT INTO room_prices(hotel_id, room_id, period_id, meal_plan_id, price) 
    SELECT $hotel_id, $room_id, $periodId, $mealPlanId, $price
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE price = $price;
```

Comment: ok I will try.. before that I am asking for to make it sure. will it check all the hotel_id, room_id, period_id,meal_plan_id columns before it update the price column?

Comment: @Yasitha . . . Yes, if you have a unique index on those four columns.

Comment: In My case hotel_id, room_id, meal_plan_id is not unique fields in this table. so this is not going to work for me.

Comment: @Yasitha . . . The logic of your code is to prevent duplicates in the table.  That leads me to think that you really do want to prevent duplicates in the table.